# Function that determines if a sequence in an object contains 1 and 4, and all other number are between 1 and 4

Tags: r

So basically, I have a matrix which contains mans rows and 4 columns, which each column having a number between 1 and 6. How can I write a `which` function that goes through the matrix and isolates the sequences that contain a 1 and a 4, and all other entries are less than 5?

I am pretty new to R, so sorry if my terminology is incorrect. But right now, my function looks like:

```
which(max(x[,1:4] == 4 & 1 %in% x[,1:4])
```

What can I replace `x[,1:4]` with so my code executes the way I need it to?

Comment: when you call it a sequence, are you implying that entries <5 should be sandwiched between a 1 and 4? or `all(x < 5, c(1, 4) %in% x)`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this

```
set.seed(12)
num_rows <- 100
x <- matrix(sample(6, num_rows*4, replace = TRUE), nrow = num_rows)
w <- which(pmin(x[, 1], x[, 2], x[, 3], x[, 4]) == 1 & pmax(x[, 1], x[, 2], x[, 3], x[, 4]) == 4)
x[w, ]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    1    3    4    1
#> [2,]    4    4    1    4
#> [3,]    4    1    3    1
```